# If we were to observe a cluster of planets from a star's magnetic north, which direction would they appear to orbit? Clockwise or counter clockwise?

Tags: magnetic-fields, orbital-motion, solar-system

I have a question, and it's been a topic of great discussion amongst my peers.

If we look at galaxies or clusters of planets around stars, they appear to be moving both clockwise and counter clockwise. If you looks at the same galaxies from the other side, their orbital orientation would change ie the galaxies that appear to orbit in one direction would appear to orbit in the opposite if viewed from the opposite side.

My question is this: If we were to observe a cluster of planets from a star's magnetic north (a unique fixed point), which direction would they appear to orbit around the star? Clockwise or counter clockwise?

Comment: What makes you believe that the orientation of the magnetic field is linked to the rotation of the planets?

Comment: The reason I chose  magnetic north was to use a fixed location. However, if the sun's polarity changes every 11 years then I guess my question will be this: Like our galaxy, do all galaxies rotate in the same direction or do some orbit clockwise and some anti-clockwise?

Comment: Galaxies rotate in all possible directions. You make a very important point about cosmology, though. If we would find more galaxies rotating around a preferred direction than others, then we would have a very interesting physical puzzle at hand. As far as I know that's not the case, though.

Answer (score 6):

We only have precise measurements of the magnetic field for one star i.e. the Sun. It turns out [the Sun's magnetic field flips every eleven years](http://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/the-suns-magnetic-field-is-about-to-flip/) i.e. the North and South poles switch over. This means there is no connection between the Sun's magnetic North and the orbits of the planets. Since we have no reason to suppose the Sun is special this means it is likely for all stars there is no connection between the star's magnetic North and the orbits of the planets.